# How do I make the perl script [makeglossaries] work on WinXP?

Tags: installing, miktex, glossaries

I got help yesterday on how to make \makeindex work (see link at bottom). I now realize that it would be better if I could make the perl script makeglossaries work, since I currently have to modify the call arguments for makeindex each time I want to define an additional glossary. When I try to run makeglossaries.bat from within TeXnicCenter, I get the following error message:

```
Can't execute C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries.
```

The file makeindex is the perl script, and makindex.bat is a file that calls the perl script with the following lines:

```
@rem = '-*- Perl -*-
@echo off
perl -S "%~dp0makeglossaries" %*
```

A MWE of some sample code that I would like to be able to compile follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{SEM}{SEM}{scanning electron microscope}
\newacronym{TEM}{TEM}{transmission electron microscopy}
\newacronym{UHV}{UHV}{ultra-high vacuum}

\newglossary{variables}{vrb}{var}{List of variables}
\newglossaryentry{ai}{type=variables,name={a$_i$},sort=ai,description={Distribution coefficient}}
\newglossaryentry{ciI}{type=variables,name={c$_i^{I}$},sort=ciI,description={Concentration of element i}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{First Section} \label{Intro}

Intro. At some point, we used a \gls{SEM}, and the variable \gls{ai}.

\section{List of variables} \label{LoV}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on what goes wrong?

EDIT:

1. makeindex works if used directly (from within TeXnicCenter, but without the makeglossaries perl script)

2 and 3. I am not sure to what degree the script and batch file work as intended. Here is a copy of what I did in the command prompt to examine this:

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001
>   Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries>perl makeglossaries
>   asfd ^C at - line 1.
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries>@rem = '-*- Perl -*-
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries>perl -S
>   "%~dp0makeglossaries" %* Can't execute %~dp0makeglossaries.
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries>perl -S makeglossaries
>   Can't locate Getopt/Std.pm in @INC at ./makeglossaries line 66. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at ./makeglossaries line 66.
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries>copy_makeglossaries
>   Can't execute C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
>   2.8\scripts\glossaries\copy_makeglossaries .pl.
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries>copy_makeglossaries
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries># @echo off '#' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.
>
> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries>perl -S "C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX
>   2.8\scripts\glossaries\copy_makeglossaries.pl" Can't execute C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries\copy_makeglossaries
>   .pl.

Does it look like it is working? At least it is doing something, and I guess that means that Perl is working(?). The file copy_makeglossaries.bat calls the file copy_makeglossaries.pl. I wanted to see if adding an extension to the extensionless perl script would help, but it did not change things.

---

The old question from yesterday:

[How do I make [\makeindex] work fully on my WinXP system (works on a different system)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41360/how-do-i-make-makeindex-work-fully-on-my-winxp-system-works-on-a-different-s)

Comment: I'm a little confused; do you want to run `makeglossaries` or `makeindex`? If it's the first option, I believe the full path to the script has a typo; it would be `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries` instead. `:)`

Comment: @Paulo Cereda -- Yes, there was a typo. Thank you for pointing that out. I changed it in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `:)` According to your command prompt output, the Perl interpreter is recognized, but the script execution seems to fail. I'm no Perl expert, but I think your Perl distribution is the one to blame (maybe it's somehow broken). `:(`

Comment: `Can't locate Getopt/Std.pm` Yep. Looks like a broken module path or a missing module for Getopt.

Comment: Thanks for the input. :) I will try two things: re-installing Perl and also updating to the latest glossaries package. I think that my MiKTeX 2.8 distribution came with some kind of Perl. Could it be a problem that I installed Strawberry Perl on top of that? I had the same problems before and after installing Strawberry Perl.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install Perl. There's a free version for Windows: [ActivePerl Community Edition](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

To debug, don't start with the editor but

1. Check if `makeindex` works at all, run it yourself
2. Test the Perl script
3. Test the batch script
4. Now you could test the editor integration

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already installed Strawberry Perl, and as far as I can tell, I can run Perl from the Command Prompt. Would it be better to install ActivePerl?

Comment: If it runs, then I would keep it. See [Which version of Perl should I use on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513/which-version-of-perl-should-i-use-on-windows) or [Should I choose ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365518/should-i-choose-activeperl-or-strawberry-perl-for-windows).

Comment: I have edited my post with some testing of makeindex from the command prompt. I am not sure what to do next.